# UIScrollView: what is the difference between contentOffset and bounds.origin?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autorotate

I have implemented an UIScrollView delegate as:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) scrollView {
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds ; 
    CGPoint scrollLoc = scrollView.contentOffset ;

    NSLog(@"bounds: %@ offset:%@"
        ,   NSStringFromCGRect(bounds)
        ,   NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollLoc)) ;
}
```

And whatever I do, scrolling or rotating the device, it seems that `contentOffset` and `bounds.origin` are always the same.

Why do we need a contentOffset if that is the same as the bounds origin, or what is the case when both are actually different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollingViewContent/ScrollingViewContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH6-SW2):

> The contentOffset property is always the current location of the
>   top-left corner of the scroll bounds, whether scrolling is in progress
>   or not.

Comment: So to clarify, if UIScrollView is in the process of scrolling does the *bounds.origin* CGPoint specify place BEFORE  scrolling happened (the last time it was immobilized) and by contrary *contentOffset* CGPoint is actualized as we scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they both offer you the same information, one as a rectangle with his width and height and the other just the origin point.

Answer (score 0):

The View is at the same location in both case, but the content may be moved within the view if you use a ContentOffset.

You will find usefull information in episode 9.Image View ... of the Standford University series :

http://itunes.apple.com/fr/itunes-u/developing-apps-for-ios-hd/id395605774

Comment: Changing the origin of the `bounds` property has the same effect as changing the `contentOffset`.

Comment: @jlehr Although I cannot use setContentOffset:animated: in the case of boudns.origin. But I suppose you can anyway animate it with UIView animations.

Comment: It would be useful to specify where in the 1 hour video we would find the context for this answer.